# Error: Permission denied to access property '$' - iFrame

Tags: html, iframe, modal-dialog, lightbox

I have a problem using an iFrame in an Bootstrap Modal. Its a News System, and i load the News Content from an iFrame from another Subdomain. Everything works fine, if a user clicks on an Image from the any news item, i want to open a Lightbox (Fancybox) in the Parent Window. Thats normally not the problem, i am using something like this:

```
// so i know its an Popup / has an iFrame (class Popup is when it is opened in an BS Modal) - otherwise ill go to my news size and show the article there.

$('a[rel="lightbox"]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    if ($(this).closest('body').hasClass('popup')) {
        parent.$.fancybox({

// this is without any popup

    $.fancybox({
        href: link,
        ...
```

My Images are on another Domain - like static.site.com. When ill go to news.site.com - and open an Popup (now its from the same domain) - and click an image - everything is fine, the

```
 parent.$
```

works fine.

But, from the main site (www.site.com) when i am opening the Modal (Contents from news.site.com) and then click on the image (static.site.com) ill the the following error:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property '$'
```

I have already allowed the PHP Header to load content from another subdomain - but ill get still this error.

Do i need to use JSONP (to load the Content of the Page as HTML?) - or is there another, simpler Solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set both domains to the [same top level domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) in JavaScript:

> A page may change its own origin with some limitations. A script can set the value of document.domain to a subset of the current domain. If it does so, the shorter domain is used for subsequent origin checks.

So if you have `static.example.com` and `news.example.com` you should include this JavaScript to run before you try any cross-frame access:

```
document.domain = 'example.com';
```

You will need to run this code in both windows.